# Views not rotating to landscape-mode after iOS6 update

Tags: ios, ipad, ios-simulator, orientation, landscape-portrait

I have my interface orientation set to `Landscape (left home button)` in my `-Info.plist` file and everything was working fine before I updated to the latest version of xcode. The simulator is now running iOS 6. When I launch my app in the simulator, it starts in portrait mode, but the content is shown as if the app doesn't support landscape mode. They're rotated 90 degrees to the right and the content doesn't fit (I never meant to support portrait mode)

Any ideas what's changed in iOS 6 and how I can get my views to rotate?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It appears that iOS6 requires that you set a rootViewController to your window, rather than adding the controller's view as a subview.

You probably have somewhere in your code:

```
[window addSubview:yourController.view];
```

Try changing it to :

```
[window setRootViewController:yourController];
```

instead.

Comment: @Sled, you should mark this as the solution to your problem.  (And it fixed my issue as well, thanks Elias.)

Comment: Yea I was planning on doing that, I forgot.